# Webpack require other libraries

Tags: webpack, photoswipe

I am trying to get my assets working with a webpack configuration.

I have split all my JS from one large .js file into separate ones with a main `application.js` file that `require`s them all.

Now one of these files:- `gallery.js` needs the `PhotoSwipe` library. I have it installed in my `node_modules` directory and at the top of `gallery.js` I have:

```
require('photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.min');
require('photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min');
```

But when running the page, in the console I get:

```
gallery.js?a942:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoSwipe is not defined
    at openPhotoSwipe (gallery.js?a942:77)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (gallery.js?a942:89)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (vendor.js:5530)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (vendor.js:5338)
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong so I can fix the undefinedness of PhotoSwipe?

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things to get this work.

1. Assign the `require`d libraries into variable and use that wherever needed like,

   ```
   var PhotoSwipe = require('photoswipe');
   var PhotoSwipeUIDefault = require('photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default');
   ```
2. Use `ProvidePlugin` to populate the `PhotoSwipe` variable for you like,

   ```
   plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         PhotoSwipe: 'photoswipe',
         PhotoSwipeUI_Default: 'photoswipe/src/js/ui/photoswipe-ui-default.js'
     })
   ]
   ```

Comment: Fantastic! Much appreciated.  Out of interest, which is the preferred approach?

Comment: if you are using these two libs in multiple places, then go with approach 2 otherwise good to go with approach 1.

Comment: @rctneil I believe it's fair to give the answer an upvote vs just the simple accepted checkmark alone.  This answer saved me a lot of headaches, it deserves another vote.

Comment: @YesBarry All sorted. Thanks for the heads up!